# Xcode - update ViewController label text from different view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I have two view Controllers in my project `ViewController`, `SettingsView`. Here I am trying to update the `ViewController's` label, when i click on the `SettingsView's` back button. `NSLog` is working fine, but the label is not updating...
Please help me....

**SettingsView.m**

```
-(IBAction)backToMain:(id) sender {

  //calling update function from ViewController
    ViewController * vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [vc updateLabel];
    [vc release];

  //close the SettingsView 
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)updateLabel
{
    NSLog(@"Iam inside updateLabel");
   self.myLabel.text = @"test";
}
```

Could you please tell me whats wrong with my code? Thank you!

Comment: +1. At least you have tried something..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to implement protocols for that. Follow this:

1) In SettingView.h define protocol like this

```
 @protocol ViewControllerDelegate

 -(void) updateLabel;

  @end
```

2)  Define property in .h class and synthesis in .m class..

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) id <ViewControllerDelegate> viewControllerDelegate;
```

3)  In SettingsView.m `IBAction`

```
  -(IBAction)backToMain:(id) sender 
 {
     [viewControllerDelegate updateLabel];
 }
```

4) In ViewController.h adopt protocol like this

```
@interface ViewController<ViewControllerDelegate>
```

5) In viewController.m include this line in `viewDidLoad`

```
settingView.viewControllerDelegate=self
```

Comment: Does this work if if I use a `UIView` and `UIViewController`. In my case, `SettingView` is my `UIViewController`, and my `UIView` is like shebi's `ViewController`. When I try to do something similar to `SettingsView.viewControllerDelegate = self` in my `UIView`'s `initWithFrame`, viewControllerDelegate isn't autofilled. It says Property not found on object ViewController. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Your label is not updating because , you are trying to call `updateLabel` method with a new instance.

You should call `updateLabel` of the original instance of viewcontroller from which you have presented your modal view.

you can use a delegate mechansim or NSNotification to do the same.

Delegate mechnaism would be clean. NSNotification is quick and dirty.

Answer (score 0):

You are not exactly calling the correct `vc`. This is because you are creating a new instance of that class and calling the `updateLabel` of that instance.

You have a few options.

1. Either implement it as a `delegate` callBack (delegate messagePassing, or delegate notification - however you want to call it) to notify that class instance to call the `updateLabel` method.
2. Use the original instance `VC` as a `dependency injection` into the class that you are on right now, and use that instance to call the `updateLabel`
3. Use NSNotifications / NSUserDefaults to communicate between viewControllers and setup a notification system for your actions. This is quite easy, but not really great in the long run.

I would RECOMMEND option 1 (or) option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare like this in SettingsView class:

```
 UILabel *lblInSettings;// and synthesize it
```

Now assign like below when you presenting Settings viewController:

```
settingsVC.lblInSettings=self.myLabel;
```

Then whatever you update in lblInSettings it will be present in MainView obviously.... 
no need for any delegate methods or updating methods.

```
Means if you assign at the time of dismissing like
lblInSettings.text=@"My new value";
then self.myLabel also will be updated.
```

Let me know if you have any queries?