# Changing a label in another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have a program with multiple views, one of them has labels (LabelView for this question), the other has text fields(TextView for this question). I would like to take the info from the text fields, and put it on the label, I think the easiest way to do this by calling a method LabelView from TextView.

I have tried a couple things:

1. I tried putting a method in LabelView that changed the label's values with parameters. Then calling the method in TextView and passing the data through the parameters.
2. I tried making a delegate, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052594/xcode-update-viewcontroller-label-text-from-different-view) question. Unfortunately the last step (add `settingView.viewControllerDelegate=self` to the `viewDidLoad` method) failed. `settingView` was an undeclared identifier.

Does anyone know what I should do?

EDIT: Here is some I have done, using Xman's Parent/Child view idea. This is in TextView.m:

```
NSInteger curScore = [self.ToP1Score.text integerValue];
NSInteger curPhase = [self.ToP1Phase.text integerValue];
self.ToP1Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (curScore += [self.player1Txt.text integerValue])];
if ([self.player1Txt.text integerValue] < 50) {
    self.ToP1Phase.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (curPhase += 1)];
}
```

Comment: Follow this answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1

Comment: create globally varible

Answer (score 2):

**Two ways to achieve this.**

1) Make `ChildView` as a childView of `ParentView` so that you can directly access `ParentView` properties in `ChildView` as following

**ParentView.h**

```
@interface ParentView : UIView
@property (nonatomic,strong) UITextField *mytextField;
@end
```

**ChildView.h**

```
#import "ParentView.h"

@interface ChildView : ParentView
@property (nonatomic,strong) UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

2) Use Notification

Put this in `FirstView` where the `textField` is :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"sendData" object:yourTextFiels userInfo:nil];
```

Put this in `SecondView` where your `Label` is.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeLabelValue:) name:@"sendData" object:nil];
```

and also this method

```
-(void)changeLabelValue(NSNotification *)iRecognizer {

    UITextField *myTextField = iRecognizer object];

    //Here You can change the value of label
}
```

**Hope this will help you.**

Comment: How do I make a view a child view of a different view?

Comment: use addSubview method

Comment: @Xman, it's weird. I tried the parent/child view thing, but the labels wouldn't change.

Comment: so self.ToP1Score is the TextView whose value you want to pass into UILabel which is another class ?

Comment: Sorry, self.ToP1Score is the label I want to change. I want to add the value of self.player1Txt to the value of self.ToP1Score and then but that value into the label. I know how to do that, but I don't know how to change the label. I can take this to chat sometime if you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36912/discussion-between-donyorm-and-xman)

Comment: @Xman here's a link to the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36912/discussion-between-donyorm-and-xman

Answer (score 0):

suppose you are passing some text from firststViewController to secondViewController,
then in firststviewcontroller add these lines of code

```
-(IBAction)goToNextScreen:(id)sender
{
  secondViewController *newVc = [[secondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];
 // or if you are using storyboard
 // NewViewController *newVc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
 newVc.text = @" Your text ";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVc animated:YES]; 
}
```

in 2ndViewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface secondViewController : UIViewController
{
  NSString text;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString text;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;

@end
```

in .m file

```
#import "secondViewController.h"

@interface secondViewController ()

@end

@implementation secondViewController
@synthesize text,lbl;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   lbl.text = text;
}
@end
```

hope this will help you.. Dont forget to up vote...