# Its possible to change font of UILabel from other ViewController class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, uipopover

I have a ViewController which consist of `UILabel` and `UIButton`.  OnClick `UIButton` a `popOver` present which show `tableView`. each cell of `tableView` represent different font option.

I want to change the font of `UILabel`  based on user selected font from `tableViewCell`. how i can achieve this as my `UILabel` and `tableView` are in different viewController class.

Please help me.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   var row = indexPath.row
   // How to update label from here
}
```

**Edit** : I fond this answer but not able  to understand as its return in objective c  [update ViewController label text from different view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052594/xcode-update-viewcontroller-label-text-from-different-view)

Comment: Use Protocol and delegates or blocks or NotificationCenter

Comment: @Mrug can u refer some example

Comment: Checkout this, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/swift-from-scratch-delegation-and-properties--cms-23445
 
and this
http://codewithchris.com/learn-swift-from-objective-c-part3/

Comment: It's not actually about Font, Its related to handle Callbacks, you need to just Implement any of three things, I would prefer Protocol and delegate at initial level, It will allow you to give Call back to your initial Viewcontroller so then after I think you already know what to do, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delegate. In your `popover` Swift file create such protocol:

```
protocol PopoverDelegate {
    func didSelectFont(font: UIFont)
}
```

In your `popover` class create such implementation of newly created protocol:

```
class popoverviewcontroller : UITableViewController {
    var delegate: PopoverDelegate?

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       var row = indexPath.row
       // How to update label from here
       delegate.didSelectFont(youFontHere)
    }
}
```

Now in your main view controller, if you are presenting your `popover` programmatically, you should set your popover's `delegate` property to `self`. If your are presenting popover from storyboard, just handle segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! popoverviewcontroller
    destination.delegate = self
}
```

Now implement delegate method:

```
func didSelectFont(font: UIFont) {
    //Update label's font
}
```

And of course don't forget to add delegate to your main view controller:

```
class mainViewController: UIViewController, PopoverDelegate { ...
```

Hope it helps!